# remove ^M from solaris by perl one liner on the same file

Tags: bash, solaris, perl

usually in order to remove the ^M from file we do

```
dos2unix test.txt test.txt

tr -d '\r' < old.file > new.file
```

but this approach insist to create new file

if we do not want to create another file then the solution is:
example of perl one liner

```
perl -pi -e 's/^M//g' file1
```

I tried it on Solaris 
but for unclear reasons, the ^M still exist in the file?

please advice what its wrong here

Comment: How are you typing `^M`? It needs to be one single control character, not two characters `^` and `M`.

Comment: The perl command is creating a new file implicitly.

Comment: On Solaris 11 you can use the GNU tools like gsed which has inline replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl needs a `\r` as well.

```
perl -pi -e 's/^M//g' file1
               ^^ - should be \r
```

Although actually, you probably *just* want to stick with line endings.

```
perl -pi -e 's,\r\n,\n,g' file1
```

Although actually - you don't need perl for this. `sed` is perfectly capable:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's,\r\n$,\n,g' file1
```

Comment: Solaris `sed` doesn't have a `-i` option and doesn't support `\r` and `sed` pattern space (any implementation) don't contain `\n` (you'd need `s/^M$//` where `^M` would be a CR character).

Comment: what @StéphaneChazelas means at the end of his comment is that the `^M` shown there is 1 (special) caracter, displayed as `^M` in vi (or with cat -v), but entered with:  `ctrl` + `v` `ctrl` + `m`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `\r`, not `^M` to match carriage return characters. `^M` has removed all `M` characters at the beginning of the line, so you may want to check your file is still OK...